# Span set of a matriecs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, span

I am not sure if my answer is correct.

If $$S=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
a &b \\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix}\;\middle\vert\;  ad=0 \quad a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$
it means that or $a=0$ or $d=0$ or both of them equals $0$. Then is
$$\mathrm{span}(\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
 a&b \\ 
 c& 0
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr),\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
0 &b \\ 
 c & d
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr))= S$$

If not so, what is $k$ so $\mathrm{span}(k)=s$?

Comment: I think the span is only the terms in $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

We know that $V=M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a $4$-dimensional real vector space. Hence $U:={\rm span}{S}$ is a subspace of dimension $r\le 4$. Note that $S$ is *not* a linear subspace.
We clearly have $r\ge 4$, since every matrix in $V$ is a linear combination of matrices in $S$. Hence $\dim U=4$, so that the span of $S$ is equal to $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Edit: The answer refers to the original question, which is a well known question.
The new one is less interesting and has a trivial asnwer.

Comment: I edited the questions. Does it seems right? @Dietrich Burde

Comment: No, the spane of all these matrices equals $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, but not $S$, because $S\neq M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I edited again. (the last question)
But notice that we have the term that $ad=0$ . @Dietrich Burde 
What is the group $k$ that spans $S$?

Comment: $S$ is not a vector space (it is not closed under addition), so there is nothing that spans it. Given any subset $k$ of a vector space, the span of $k$ is also a vector space (which $S$ is not).